# Facebook User Id mapping with messenger recipient_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

How can i map the facebook userid (obtained via login request permissions) with the messenger recipient_id ? Is it possible to use account linking in messenger for this and if how exactly?

Comment: Account linking is to link the messenger user to an account in _your_ system. // Facebook made the ID you get in messenger page-scoped for a reason. There is no direct way to link that to an app-scoped or global user id.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, they are not providing a way to map between these two ids. However my requirement was to send some data to messenger account using the Facebook login. So the correct way to do this to use 'Send to messenger' plugin. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger 

This is fairly simple to integrate and it will trigger a authentication event to the webhook (POST method) of messenger application.

Thank you for you thoughts.